# Moving columns containg "Total" at the end of the pivot(after paste special) if the cells of second row contain the word "Total"

Tags: excel, vba, loops, if-statement, string-comparison

' If the cells of second row contain the word "Total" ,I want to copy paste the entire column of that cell to the end of the table.The following code gives no output. Can someone please help me identify my mistake?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mzfWi.jpg)

```
Dim PRTSLastRow As Long
Dim PRTSLastCol As Long
Dim ColLtr As String
Dim LastColLtr As String
Dim Total As String
Dim j as Integer

W = ActiveWorkbook.Name
PRTSLastCol = Worksheets("PRTSCarrierCount").Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
PRTSLastRow = Worksheets("PRTSCarrierCount").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
j = 1
Workbooks(W).Sheets("PRTSCarrierCount").Activate

For i = 1 To PRTSLastCol
    Total = Cells(1, i).Value
    If InStr(1, CStr(Total), "Total") > 0 Then
        ColLtr = Replace(Cells(1, i).Address(True, False), "$1", "")
        LastColLtr = Replace(Cells(1, PRTSLastCol + j).Address(True, False), "$1", "")
        Range("ColLtr & 1: & ColLtr & PRTSLastRow").Select
        'Columns("ColLtr & : & ColLtr").Select
        Selection.Copy
        Range("LastColLtr & 1").Select
        ActiveSheet.Paste
        j = j + 1
    End If
Next i
```

Comment: Can you show what the before and after would look like? Are you trying to find which column has the word total in and move to end (this being a range copied from a pivottable)??

Comment: Uploaded an image of sample input/output.

Comment: You want every total column repeated at the end? And cascade is in row 2?

Comment: Yes, That is what I am trying to accomplish by the above code. "Total" is in 2nd row. Please see the image. later on, I also intend to work on removing those total columns present in the middle using another loop.

Comment: You could loop row 2 to [last column](https://www.rondebruin.nl/win/s9/win005.htm) using [Find](https://excelmacromastery.com/excel-vba-find/) (find total) and collect the entire columns where found using [Union](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/application-union-method-excel) and then write all that out at the end of the range in one go. Offset(from last column by 1 column)

Comment: Okay..I will try using "Find" & "Union" function. Can you also tell me why my above code is not working? What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this?

```
Option Explicit

Sub Thing()

    Dim PRTSLastRow As Long
    Dim PRTSLastCol As Long
    Dim ColLtr As String
    Dim LastColLtr As String
    Dim Total As String
    Dim W As Workbook
    Dim i As Long
    Dim ws As Worksheet

    Set W = ThisWorkbook 'Or ActiveWorkbook
    Set ws = W.Worksheets("PRTSCarrierCount")

    PRTSLastRow = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    PRTSLastCol = GetLastCol(ws, 1)

    With ws

        For i = 1 To PRTSLastCol

            Total = LCase$(.Cells(1, i).Text)

            If InStr(1, Total, "total") > 0 Then

                ColLtr = Replace(.Cells(1, i).Address(True, False), "$1", "")
                .Range(ColLtr & "1:" & ColLtr & PRTSLastRow).Copy .Cells(1, GetLastCol(ws, 1) + 1)

                i = i + 1

            End If

        Next i

    End With

End Sub

Public Function GetLastCol(ByVal ws As Worksheet, rowNum As Long) As Long

    With ws
        GetLastCol = .Cells(rowNum, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    End With

End Function
```

Or with `Find`

```
Public Sub Thing2()

    Dim PRTSLastRow As Long
    Dim PRTSLastCol As Long
    Dim ColLtr As String
    Dim LastColLtr As String
    Dim Total As String
    Dim W As Workbook
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim searchRng As Range

    Set W = ThisWorkbook                         'Or ActiveWorkbook
    Set ws = W.Worksheets("PRTSCarrierCount")   
    PRTSLastCol = GetLastCol(ws, 1)        
    Total = "total"

    With ws

        PRTSLastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
        Set searchRng = .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(1, PRTSLastCol))

        Dim gatheredRange As Range
        Set gatheredRange = GatherRanges(Total, searchRng, PRTSLastRow)

        If Not gatheredRange Is Nothing Then
            gatheredRange.Copy .Cells(1, GetLastCol(ws, 1) + 1)
        End If

     End With

End Sub

Public Function GatherRanges(ByVal Total As String, ByVal searchRng As Range, ByVal PRTSLastRow As Long) As Range

    Dim foundCell As Range
    Set foundCell = searchRng.Find(Total)

    If foundCell Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "Search term not found"
        End
    End If

    Dim firstfoundCellAddress As String
    firstfoundCellAddress = foundCell.Address

    Dim gatheredRange As Range
    Set gatheredRange = foundCell.Resize(PRTSLastRow, 1)

    Do

        Set foundCell = searchRng.FindNext(foundCell)
        Set gatheredRange = Union(gatheredRange, foundCell.Resize(PRTSLastRow, 1))

    Loop While firstfoundCellAddress <> foundCell.Address

    Set GatherRanges = gatheredRange

End Function
```

Reference:

1. https://excelmacromastery.com/excel-vba-find/

Comment: In 1st code, I replaced "Total = LCase$(.Cells(1, i).Text)" by "Total = .Cells(1, i).Value" and it still works fine. Can you please tell me why did you use that?

Comment: Lcase is in case total versus Total. So works for both. LCase$ is a typed function of LCase so more efficient.  Using .Text ensures that a string is returned from the cell. I think you were doing a string conversion before. With .Text you don’t need that.